# Interpreting the results of the JITStats report in Perfview

Tags: c#, .net, jit, perfview

I've collected some PerfView results for my ASP.NET application, and can see that it is spending an enormous amount of time JITting. This conclusion is matched by the performance counter "% time spent in JIT" - this averages around 30%, which is pretty bad.

As I have a high throughput application (100s of requests per second) this is causing an enormous stress on the CPU.

I can see a huge amount of JITs for a particular method:

```
dynamicClass.lambda_method(pMT: 000007FE9AE54688)
```

How can I map that address to my source code to determine what the bad code is?

Comment: It is low-level glue, I'd guess you don't like LinqDataSource that much.  You need more caching.

Comment: Thanks - I kinda figured it was something internal. I was hoping to work out a way to look at a stack trace, perhaps. Although we use LINQ quite a bit, we don't use LINQ compiled queries, which I suspect would be the best optimization to perform.

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this? Up against the same task now, would love to hear any tips on making progress!